# Macbook pro running out of memory and sometimes freezing for a while

Tags: macos, memory, macbook-pro

I am having performance issues with my MacBookPro.  It just seems to be running out of memory constantly to the point that my music jumps and also the screen will freeze momentarily and then when I check Activity Monitor there is sometimes only a few megabytes of memory available.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be the issue?

See attached screen shot.[image]

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to have a screenshot of the problem actually occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling flash, it seems to trash performance on the Mac mini I use at work.

Comment: In Settings>Flash I clicked the Advanced tab and clicked deauthorize this computer and it doesn't seem to actually do anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I should've been clearer I meant disabling it in your web browser there's add-ons for Chrome/Firefox etc that let you disable it for example http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/flash-block-selectively-block-flash-elements-chrome/